# Run PHP code 15 min before or when WooCommerce Booking is about to start

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I know I can run code when an order is completed, but I'm trying to execute code 15 min before a booking is about to start.

Maybe checking every 15 or 30 min, if an order is about to start and execute the code if that is possible.

Any help works

Comment: Why not use a cronjob for this?

Comment: How could I do that? how could I catch the upcoming bookings?

Comment: By selecting the data through a query?

Answer (score 0):

if you have plesk, make custom function trigered by link and add chron job to plesk
if don't have plesk access https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/cron_schedules/